# Problemas de recepção no sinal do módulo GPS

Tags: c++, arduino, gps, automatização

Estou tentando desenvolver um programa para capturar coordenadas pelo módulo GPS e enviar as informações para um servidor concatenado em forma de url, que irá tratar as informações e exibir minha localização através da API do Google Maps, mas a princípio, estou testando o envio das coordenadas por SMS, para um número específico, só que estou com um problema na recepção do sinal do GPS, onde as coordenadas estão vindo zeradas, e não está capturando minha real localização. Vale ressaltar que já fiz testes individuais tanto no módulo GPS como no Shield GSM, e todos os dois funcionam independentes, o problema aparece quando se tenta juntar os dois componentes. Segue código abaixo:

```
void setup()
{
  // Serial PC <-> Arduino
  Serial.begin(19200);
  // GsM Arduino <-> GSM
  GsM.begin(19200);
  // GpS Arduino <-> GPS
  GpS.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  envia_sms_gps();
}// end loop

// Funções Gerais

// Envia SMS com link google maps de localização e avisa a tentativa  de furto
void envia_sms_gps()
{
  displayGPSInfo();

// Envia SMS https://maps.google.com.br/maps?q=(LAT),(LON)
  delay(300);
  GsM.print("AT+CMGF=1"); //mandando SMS em modo texto
  delay(1000);
  GsM.print("AT + CMGS = \"" + num +"\""); // numero que vamos mandar o SMS
  delay(1000);
  GsM.println(data);
  Serial.println(data);
  delay(1000);
  GsM.write(0x1A);
  data="";
  delay(300);
}

// Faz leitura do GPS e pega as coordenadas lat e long, converte os valores float para string e concatena com link do google maps
void displayGPSInfo()
{
  if(gps.location.isValid())
{    
  dado_lat=gps.location.lat();
  dado_lng=gps.location.lng();
  dtostrf(dado_lat,4,4,lat_aux);
  latParaString = String(lat_aux);
  dtostrf(dado_lng,4,4,lng_aux);
  lngParaString = String(lng_aux);
  data+=(server);
  data+=(latParaString);
  data+=",";
  data+=(lngParaString);
}
  delay(300);
}
```

Segue abaixo a saída do programa no Serial Monitor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]